# How to create a JSON structure in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a use-case to create a JSON structure in React in order to POST an API request. The JSON structure body contains objects and arrays.

Please let me know how to create it in ReactJS. 
Below is the sample JSON structure that needs to be created using ReactJS:-

```
{

      "transactionAmount": {
        "currency": "INR",
        "value": 1220.38
      },
      "transactionDate": "2020-05-18T00:00:00Z",
      "tripData": {
        "agencyBooked": false,
        "legs": [
          {
            "endLocation": {
              "countryCode": "IN",
              "city": "Delhi",
              "name": "Indira Gandhi International"
            },
             "startDate": "2020-05-22",
             "startTime": "08:00",
            "returnLeg": false,
            "startLocation": {
              "countryCode": "US",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "name": "San Francisco International"
            },
            "endTime": "21:00",
             "endDate": "2020-05-22",
            "startLocationDetail": "none"
          },
          {
              "endLocation": {
                "countryCode": "US",
              "city": "San Francisco",
              "name": "San Francisco International"
              },
              "returnLeg": true,
              "startDate": "2020-05-24",
              "startLocation": {
                 "countryCode": "IN",
              "city": "Delhi",
              "name": "Indira Gandhi International"
              },
              "startTime": "17:00"
            }
        ],
         "segmentType": {
                "category": "REQ_SEG_AIRFR",
                "code": "AIRFR"
            },
        "selfBooked": false,
        "tripType": "ROUND_TRIP"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing creating this JSON structure? There is no process involved in creating this object

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a JSON format like this.

```
const dummyObject = {
  name: 'Dummy',
  age: 22,
  about: {
    hobbies: ['soccer']
  },
  works: true
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohan- I am fetching the data from excel and with the data parsed from excel i need to create above json structure for API POST. Not sure if the above sol. will help.. will check  & get back..